# Live migrate possible among different version XenServers in one pool, with shared storage

Tags: virtualization, xenserver

We have a pool of 3 XenServers, with version 5.6 SP2, which needed to be migrated to latest version (6.1). the upgrade of pool master is complete and now the pool has one server with version 6.1 and other two servers with version 5.6 SP2. to avoid any downtime, we want to move (migrate) our Virtual machines from the old version Xenserver to upgraded xenserver. But the live migration is not working. what methods are available besides live migration, between two different version XenServers? Also, is there any way to change the home server or migrate the machine that is turned off? (Note: All VMs are stored on Shared storage on a SAN).

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't it working?  Any error messages to speak of?

Answer (score 1):

Live migration between 5.6 and 6.x pools is not working. 
I think, the best (and only ?) option would be to create a snapshot of the 5.6 VM's and export it. Then import the VM on the new (6.x) pool.By creating a snapshot you can avoid downtime.